# help compiling xoscope-2.2

Tags: compiling, gtk

I have some experience with Ubuntu and the command line but I'm totally new to compiling. when I run ./configure I get a package requirement not met error that says gtk+ not found.

I have verified that two versions of gtk+ are installed(2+3),build-essentials are there, PKG_CONFIG_PATH is set(used apt-file search to find the path), everything that could be has been upgraded.

I've been at this for two days and have tried everything I found on the internet. I could really use some help. I apologize if this is a redundant question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the *development* package for GTK+ installed (`libgtk2.0-dev`)?

Comment: Yes I neglected to mention that. Thanks for your interest! I searched up and down the internet and found a lot of useful suggestions and a lot of Ubuntu documentation. I tried everything I found. Incidentally I'm running 1804 bionic beaver.

Comment: So, what does `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-2.0` report? what version of Ubuntu are you using? If you pastebin the `config.log` file perhaps someone will be able to spot what's wrong.

Comment: hi! thanks to a fellow user I was able to make considerable progress. make install returned error 2. im going to dig into it a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following to get all the dev libraries you need;

```
sudo apt-get install libgtkdataboxmm-dev fftw3-dev
```

Then do your  ./configure && make

Comment: hey that was great!  configure went without a hitch. so did make I think. make install returned a definite error2. i want to dig into this before i ask for more help. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As [`xoscope` is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=xoscope) in all supported Ubuntu versions, you should rely on the power APT.

Install package's build dependencies with

```
sudo apt-get build-dep xoscope
```

and continue as you tried.

Answer (score 0):

**As** mentioned on @NOrbert answer section, `xoscope` package available in all supported Ubuntu versions. just follow the command :

```
sudo apt-get install xoscope libgtk2.0-dev
```

**If** you install `xoscope` package from build source-code like this [github](https://github.com/imrehg/xoscope), you should install the dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install libsx svgalib g3vga
```

and try compiling your source-code again!!

```
./configure;
```

**Make** sure when configuring the source-code, you have a log like :

```
...
Checking: <depend-packages> is YES
...
```

Instead

```
...
Checking: <depend-packages> is NO
...
```

If all the dependencies is right, you can install the `.makefile` files :

```
make; make install;
```

Hope this helps;